# Hold notification covers comment button

Tags: bug, android-app

I had a question put on hold. When I tried to comment it, it was not possible since the comment button was covered by the hold notification panel.

I could solve it by logging in through a Web browser.

Stack Exchange App, Android Kit-Kat, Galaxy Note 3

Suggestion: Rewrite the app so questions on hold can be commented using the app.

Comment: That is true. This question is a duplicate.